# Density of $\mathrm{span} \{ f(\cdot - n) : n \in \Bbb Z \}$ in $C(\mathbb R)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, approximation-theory

I recently came across a [survey paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/SAT/papers/1/1.pdf) by Allan Pinkus. This paper contains the following result:

Suppose that $g \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ has support in an interval of length at most $2\pi$. If $f=\hat g$ is the Fourier transform of $g$ then
$$
\mathrm{span} \{ f(\cdot - n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}
$$
is dense in $C(\mathbb R)$ (in the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets).

I was wondering if similar results holds for other types of functions. Is there a theory about such functions or is someone of you aware of papers dicussing results in this direction?

After the above result Pinkus mentions that this is a "simple example within a general theory" and refers to papers by Atzmon and Nikolski. However, as I see it, these papers discuss the existence of functions with the above property (in more general spaces than $C(\mathbb R)$) rather than explicit examples of functions with the above property.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think it's fairly easy to see that, for $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the vector space generated by the translates of $f$ (by all real numbers) is dense in $L^2$ iff the Fourier transform $\hat f$ (in the $L^2$ sense) is nonzero a.e. I can write down details if you want (but there's nothing smart or surprising).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%27s_Tauberian_theorem

Comment: The translation operator is thus *cyclic*. There is a lot of literature about cyclic, supercyclic or even *hypercyclic* opearotors.